# WCF memory Usage increasing

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, wcf-binding

i have a WCF Client and a WCF service. For testing when i continually call a WCF method synchronously the memory usage jumps up by about 1 mb each time. How can i stop this happening ?

```
MyService.JobsClient Client = new MyService.JobsClient();
Client.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServicePath"]);
Client.WCFGetSystemState(System.Environment.MachineName);
```

Comment: Are you sure this memory is not reclaimed later? Remember, the GC runs as needed. It doesn't run every time some object is no longer used.

Comment: Do you close the client when you're done with it?

Comment: @MikeStockdale No and that was the problem thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure that you close your client after you use it. You can follow this pattern (taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735103%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
MyService.JobsClient Client = new MyService.JobsClient();
Client.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServicePath"]);
try
{
    Client.WCFGetSystemState(System.Environment.MachineName); 
    Client.Close();
}
catch (TimeoutException timeout)
{
    // Handle the timeout exception.
    Client.Abort();
}
catch (CommunicationException commException)
{
    // Handle the communication exception.
    Client.Abort();
}
```